# cxf DefaultSecurityTokenServiceProvider response based on SAML version

Tags: java, spring, cxf, x509certificate, saml

I am newly working with CXF STS and came across below requirements, which I am unable to proceed

1 How can the DefaultSecurityTokenServiceProvider from CXF STS provide SAML assertion of different versions say 1.1 or 2.0 . I have an assumption on it.Please correct me if am wrong. The bean property for  DefaultSecurityTokenServiceProvider:services

```
<property name="services" ref="myServiceList" />
<bean id="myServiceList" class="org.apache.cxf.sts.service.StaticService">
    <property name="endpoints" ref="wspAllowedEndpoints" />
</bean>
<util:list id="wspAllowedEndpoints">
    <value>http://localhost:8080/doubleit/services/doubleit.*</value>
</util:list>
```

It requests the wsdl for all allowed services, reads the policy element,

```
<sp:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate>
                          <t:TokenType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV1.1</t:TokenType>
                          <t:KeyType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/SymmetricKey</t:KeyType>
                          <t:KeySize>256</t:KeySize>
                       </sp:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate>
```

ans based on SAMLV1.1 or SAMLV2.0 it determines which version of SAML assertion to be sent in response

2 How can I read the SAML assertion from `org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient` as text

```
**saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Version="2.0" ID="s2b7afe8e21a0910d027dfbc94ec4b862e1fbbd9ab" IssueInstant="2007-12-10T11:39:48Z"**
```

so I can put them in header and work with SOAPUI as client?

Answer (score 0):

The STS will issue a SAML 1.1 or 2.0 token by default depending on the TokenType that is sent. Thus to support both 1.1 + 2.0, no action is needed in terms of the STS configuration.

The STSClient will return a SecurityToken Object. You can get the DOM representation of the returned token via stsClient.getToken(). You can then use something like WSS4J's  DOM2Writer.nodeToString(node) to convert to a String.

Colm.

Comment: Thanks Colm for your response.Its more clear now.One more query I have is, `<util:list id="wspAllowedEndpoints">
    <value>http://localhost:8080/doubleit/services/doubleit.*</value>
</util:list>` This means more than one service provider endpoints are secure by STS. So how STS client can pass that it needs a SAML assertion for specific service provider policy. That is how SAML assertion for specific Service Provider endpoint is requested by STS client.One assumption is STS is client given to WS-Client with property `<entry key="ws-security.sts.client">`.But for STS client as individual bean?

Comment: That is if wspAllowedEndpoints has more that one services of different  policies, the STS may client need to request for corresponding specific SAML assertion. So how this can be achieved? Please correct if I am missing something here

Comment: The STSClient can send an "AppliesTo" URI to the STS which is matched against the list you referenced.